# Multiplexed keyboard based on MOSFET for AVR gives sometimes wrong reading

Tags: mosfet, avr, keyboard

I made simple example for multiplexed keyboard 2x2 on AVR. Like schematic below:

[image]

And Source code:

```
#define F_CPU 2000000UL
// Have to be > 16*F_scl, for 100 kHz it should be greather than 1.6 MHz

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <util/twi.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define P_SCL PC5
#define P_SDA PC4

uint8_t input_no = 0;
volatile uint8_t inputs[6];
uint8_t input_keyb_no = 0;
uint8_t input_count[6][8];

void init_twi_slave(uint8_t address)
{
    DDRC  = 0x00;                           // Set input SDA, SCL
    PORTC = ~((1 << P_SCL) | (1 << P_SDA)); // Set high impedance SDA, SCL - rest pull-up
    TWAR = (address << 1);                  // Set TWI address
    TWCR = (1 << TWEN)                      // TWI Enable
         | (1 << TWIE)                      // TWI Interrupt Enable
         | (1 << TWEA);                     // TWI Acknowledge Enable
}

void inputs_handler_reset()
{
    input_no = 1;
    TWDR = inputs[0];
}

void inputs_handler()
{
    if (input_no >= 8)
    {
        TWDR = 0xFF;
        return;
    }
    
    TWDR = inputs[input_no];
    input_no++;
}

ISR(TWI_vect)
{
    switch (TW_STATUS)
    {
        case TW_ST_SLA_ACK:
            inputs_handler_reset();
            break;
        case TW_ST_DATA_ACK:
            inputs_handler();
            break;
        default:
        break;
    }

    TWCR |= (1 << TWINT);       // Clear TWI Interrupt flag
}

void init_keyboard()
{
    DDRD  = 0x00;   //Port D Input
    PORTD = 0xFF;   //PORT D Pull-up
    PORTB = 0x00;   //PORT B LOW
    DDRB  = 0xFF;   //PORT B Output
    
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        inputs[i] = 0;
        for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        input_count[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

void handle_keyboard()
{
    input_keyb_no++;
    if (input_keyb_no >= 8)
        input_keyb_no = 0;
    
    PORTB = 1 << input_keyb_no;
    _delay_loop_1(40); // = 20 us with F_OSC = 2 MHz
    
    uint8_t new_inputs = 0x00;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (PIND & (1 << i))
        {
            input_count[input_keyb_no][i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (input_count[input_keyb_no][i] < 40)
                input_count[input_keyb_no][i]++;
            else
                new_inputs |= 1 << i;
        }
    }
    inputs[input_keyb_no] = new_inputs;
}

int main(void)
{
    init_keyboard();        // Initialize keyboard
    init_twi_slave(0x20);   // Initialize TWI
    sei();                  // Enable interrupts
    
    while(1)
    {
        handle_keyboard();  // Read keyboard, set next to read
    }
}
```

Sometimes I got 0 response even if switch is closed. As I found the zeros appears in pairs for PORTB0 or for PORTB1. The voltage on PIND0 is 4.46V and for PIND1 (disconnected, same config) is full 5V.
What goes wrong?

- CPU: AT MEGA 8
- all R's: 10k
- Transistor: BSS138

Comment: The arrays inputs[] and input_count[] are declared to contain 6 elements, but the software accesses 8 elements. So e.g. writing to inputs[7] modifies some other variable behind it in memory. Try to use ROW and COLUMN names for variables. This avoids irritations. What is the real matrix size? 2x2, 6x8 or 8x8?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Let me try after fixes

Comment: @Jens Make your comment as answer to allow me mark as good answer

Comment: 10k on the bss138 gate is going to give a longer turn on time. In this application the gate resistors are not needed.

Comment: @Kartman I wanted not to exceed maximum current rating when turning (MOSFET act as capacitor). How to determine when it is needed or not?

Comment: What maximum current rating? What maximum current did you calculate? Port pin max current is usually a thermal limitation. The drivers appear as a resistance of around 40Ohms, so it is physically limited. Charging/discharging a bss148 gate will have a tiny average current.

Comment: @Kartman Yes, so I can repeat my question: How to determine when it is needed or not?

Comment: Calculate the current. You know the effective capacitance and resistance, so put this into a simulator.

Comment: For this application, it might be easier to use something like a 4051 multiplexer.

Comment: why are you using FETs in the design of the matrix keypad?

Comment: @jsotola It is not for keyboard. It is for room light switches. Some of them are connected by 3 wire, but it is needed to connect light and switch on same 3 wires, so it have to connect with GND

Comment: light switches....  next you're going to learn about radio frequency interference.  this design is cursed.

Comment: Not so much cursed, but in need of improvement. Anytime you have long wires, you really want filtering and ESD protection otherwise your system will be very unreliable. As noted earlier, a 4051 would be the start of a better solution but would still need filtering and protection.

Comment: are these switches connected to powerline voltages?

Comment: @jsotola Yes, the 230V is what AVR likes best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays inputs[] and input_count[] are declared to contain 6 elements, but the software accesses 8 elements at several places.
So e.g. writing to inputs[7] or input_count[7][i] modifies some other variable behind it in memory.

It is good practice to associate names with the array limits per #define.
Try to use variable names other than i and j to immediately see for which array index they will be used.

```
#define MATRIX_INPUTS   8
#define MATRIX_OUTPUTS  6

volatile uint8_t inputs[MATRIX_OUTPUTS];
uint8_t input_count[MATRIX_OUTPUTS][MATRIX_INPUTS];


for (uint8_t m_out = 0; m_out < MATRIX_OUTPUTS; m_out++)
{
  inputs[m_out] = 0;
  for (uint8_t m_in = 0; m_in < MATRIX_INPUTS; m_in++) {
    input_count[m_out][m_in] = 0;
  }
}

....
{
  input_keyb_no++;
  if (input_keyb_no >= MATRIX_OUTPUTS) {
    input_keyb_no = 0;
  }
}
```

I think the variable name "input_keyb_no" is a bad choice, because it is used as a kind of "cur_keyb_out".

As Kartman mentioned in a comment, you normally don't need the gate resistors, except that you want to suppress the RF emission of the switching edges via FET gate capacitance to the external wiring.